# How to make ant target to wait for the another target to complete

Tags: java, ant, selenium

In my selenium grid setup, I have to execute 2 modules initially, which will create data. Then , rest 6 modules paralelly.
Totally i have 8 targets for 8 different modules in build.xml.I have to make all 6 targets wait for initial 2 targets to complete.
1. How can i make ant target wait for the rest two targets to complete execution?
2.If i break build.xml into 2 build.xmls, which command makes 2 build files to run sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use antcall ...

```
<project name="projectName" default="initialtarget1">
<target name="initialtarget1"> 
      <....> 

      </....>
      <antcall target="initialtarget2"/> 
      <antcall target="target1"/> 
      <antcall target="target2"/> 
      <antcall target="target3"/> 
      <antcall target="target4"/> 
</target> 
<target name="initialtarget2"> 
</target> 
<target name="target1"> 
</target> 
<target name="target2"> 
</target> 
<target name="target3"> 
</target> 
<target name="target4"> 
</target> 
</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the initial two modules to execute in parallel, then the remaining six in parallel.  Kind of like:

```
Time
 |   InitialModule1 InitialModule2
 |           |              |
 |           .              |
 |                          |
 |                          .
 |   Module3 Module4 Module5 Module6 Module7 Module8
 |      |       |       |       |       |       |
 |      v       v       v       v       v       v
 V
```

If each module is run by its own Ant task: `task_one, task_two ... task_eight`, you can do this using Ant target dependencies and the [`parallel` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html).  Target dependencies specify the order of execution, something like:

```
<target name="create_data">
    <parallel>
        <task_one ... />
        <task_two ... />
    </parallel>
</target>

<target name="do_work" depends="create_data">
    <parallel>
        <task_three ... />
         .
         .
         .
        <task_eight ... />
    </parallel>
</target>
```

If each Selenium grid module is run by a series of tasks, rather than a single task you could wrap these in [`sequential`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sequential.html) tasks.  If they are implemented as separate targets, then perhaps `antcall` could be used inside the `parallel` tasks.